# How can I manually replay a tuple from a function in Apache Flink in case of run time exception?

Tags: exception, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

In storm we execute collector.fail(tuple) to replay the tuple. What is the similar approach in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

Flink takes care of this automatically, so long as checkpointing is enabled. The underlying mechanism is described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/internals/stream_checkpointing.html), but in a nutshell, Flink periodically snapshots all of the cluster's state, and restores it in the event of a failure. This includes rewinding the sources and replaying events as needed to achieve exactly-once processing semantics.

Update:

Sometimes it is necessary to loop events back through some or all of the job graph. Flink's DataSet API supports this with [iterations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/batch/iterations.html), but unfortunately, there are issues with iterations and streaming. The best available solution is to write events to a sink and re-ingest them from a source.

Comment: I have a specific business logic in flink function which is doing multiple API calls and these API calls might return some status code based on which I need to replay the same tuple.